# swift becomeFirstResponder

Tags: swift, keyboard

I need to open the keyboard.
 When the `ViewController` starts I use this function

```
func showKeyboardAndFocus(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.placeForText.resignFirstResponder()
        self.placeForText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

from `viewDidLoad` and it works correctly. 
When I close it, and try to open using the same function, it doesn't work.

Why? How can I open it second time?

Answer (score 0):

To show the keyboard:

```
self.inputTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

To hide the keyboard:

```
self.inputTextView.resignFirstResponder()
```

Show/hide second time

```
@IBAction func showKeyboardClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func closeKeyboardClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```